# Pre-soaking pulses - Is there a way to slow down fermentation?

Tags: pulses

The Scotch broth mix I use consists of pearl barley, yellow split peas, green split peas, blue peas and red split lentils. Prior to use, it requires soaking for 8-12 hours and then draining and rinsing before cooking.

Due to other commitments, I often cannot return to changing the water for 18-24 hours. This results in the mix starting to give off a distinct undesired  aroma, I assume down to fermentation.

Is there a way to slow down this reaction?

Comment: Does the answer for this question work for you?  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27641/soaking-pulses-overnight-safety-vs-refrigeration?rq=1

Comment: I saw that answer, but they don't state if refrigeration actually works.  The OP was also unclear as to how long they were leaving the beans out for, I'm not sure if they meant 24h.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Soaking pulses overnight: safety vs refrigeration](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27641/soaking-pulses-overnight-safety-vs-refrigeration)

Comment: Put it in the fridge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refrigeration is a very standard way to slow down fermentation. Use it.

I've soaked beans in the fridge for more than a week without off-flavors (but I do generally change the water every day or two, as I'm not a fan of preserving extracted oligosaccharides.)

*In my personal experience presoaking would only make much difference to the lentils, in your mixture. I came to split peas from other beans, and maintained my prior practice of pre-soaking them, but found there was very little difference if I did not do that. Well, other than making felafel with them, where they obviously need to be pre-soaked.*